# How to work with ContentProperty in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have following code
**My Page XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:Coodo.Effects;assembly=Coodo"
             x:Class="Coodo.Pages.MessagePage">


    <effects:ContainerWithShadow>
        <Label Text="123" />
    </effects:ContainerWithShadow>

</ContentPage>
```

And **ContainerWithShadow** class for storage view

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Coodo.Effects
{
    [ContentProperty("ContainerContent")]
    public class ContainerWithShadow : ContentView
    {
        public View ContainerContent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But my Label from XAML not binding to ContainerWithShadow.ContainerContent. Code don't stop on setter if I set breakpoint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**ContainerContent** property must be **BindableProperty**. Need to change code on following:

```
[ContentProperty("Conditions"), Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class ContainerWithShadow : ContentView
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty StateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ContainerWithShadowChild), typeof(object), typeof(View), propertyChanged:PropertyChanged);

    private static void PropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
    }

    public View ContainerWithShadowChild
    {
        get => (View)GetValue(StateProperty);
        set => SetValue(StateProperty, value);
    }
}
```

And code will work correctly.